# runtime error: signed integer overflow: 1037158320 + 1166803110 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp) SUMMARY:

Tags: c++

Why this overflow is happening?
i was solving leetcode pascal triangle question

**Code :**

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
 
    vector<vector<int> > generate(int numRows)
    {
        vector<vector<int> > v;
        v.push_back({ 1 });
        v.push_back({ 1, 1 });
        int r = 2;
        while (r != numRows) {
            vector<int> temp(r + 1);
            temp[0] = 1;
            temp[r] = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < r; i++) {
                temp[i] = (v[r - 1][i - 1] + v[r - 1][i]);
            }
            v.push_back(temp);
            r++;
        }

        return v;
    }
};
```

Error:
Line 12: Char 31: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 1037158320 + 1166803110 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:21:31

Comment: Which line is 12? Do you want `vector<int>` or `vector<long long>`. The error tells you the values exceed the limits of an `int`. An int is likely 32 bits.

Comment: temp[i]=(v[r-1][i-1]+v[r-1][i]); //inside for loop

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: Before continuing training your problem solving skills on leetcode, have a look here: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/signed-integers/, https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/fixed-width-integers-and-size-t/, after reading this the error message should be a lot more clear to you. Just a heads up leetcode isn't a great place to learn how to write good C++.

Comment: `long` is not allowed as a variable name, which you don't seem to be using, anyway.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `long long = 1e9 + 7;`? You're missing a variable name here

Comment: Actually i didn't get that why this overflow is being occured, as all the possible test cases are running perfectly fine in custom input but when i try to submit it, it shows the mentioned error

Comment: @VinayakTiwari You typically aren't told what all the tests cases are, and they tend to test edge cases to make sure you can handle all possible inputs. Look at the range of inputs it says you should expect and make sure you can handle the largest.

Comment: That's a sign that the judge is using additional test cases that hit some edge cases that you have not covered with your testing. You will have to find these additional test cases and add them to your tests. Make sure your testing fully explores the boundaries of the possible inputs. For example if the judge can supply 4 billion for `numRows`, make darn sure your program can handle 4 billion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur instant support, just found out the error! am posting the corrected code
btw this was my first time am asking que on stack overflow and am very pleased to see the great community support here :))

Comment: if(numRows==1){return v;}
just added that n==1 condition before while loop that was causing error by unwantedly going into loop!

Answer (score 1):

> Why this overflow is happening?"

`v[r - 1][i - 1]` and `v[r - 1][i]` are both `int`.
Their sum exceeds the max value for an `int` leading to *Undefined Behavior*.

Use wider math and types like `long long`.

Review prior code to see why such large values occur.